# How do I write a Clojure macro to create a regular expression from a String?

Tags: regex, macros, clojure

I'm creating a convenience macro. Part of the convenience is that a regular expression can be specified with just a String, rather than the #"re" notation.

The one part I can't figure out is how to get the macro to take the String and rewrite it as a Clojure regex (e.g., produce the #"re" notation). I think it's a syntax / escaping problem.

My first naive attempt (pretending I only want the String-to-regex part):

```
(defmacro mymac [mystr] `#~mystr)
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or, is there an actual function to take a String and produce a regex, instead of using the # reader macro?

Or should I just drop into Java and use java.util.regex.Pattern?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a function for it: [re-pattern](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/re-pattern)

```
user=> (re-pattern "\\d+")
#"\d+"
```

Answer (score 7):

To explain a bit more:

`#""` is a reader macro. It is resolved at read time by the reader. So there is no way to create a macro which expands into a reader macro, because the read phase is long gone. A macro returns the actual data structure representing the expanded code, not a string which is parsed again like eg. #define works in C.

j-g-faustus' answer is the Right Way(tm) to go.

Comment: Thanks kotarak. I should have realized why the reader life cycle prevents me from doing what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but doesn't this do what you want?

```
user=> (. java.util.regex.Pattern compile "mystr")
#"mystr"
```

Comment: yes it does exactly what i want. but you have to admit, not as pretty as j-g-faustus's (re-pattern "mystr")

Answer (score 0):

To match a string verbatim, ignoring special characters:

```
(defn to-regex [some-string]
  (re-pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote some-string)))
```

Then `...` will only match `...`, not `aaa` or any other three letter combination.