# dynamic regex argument in re-find function in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm using the re-find function in clojure, and have something like
this:

```
(defn some-function []
(re-find #"(?i)blah" "some sentence"))
```

What I would like is to make the "blah" dynamic, so I substituted a var for blah like this, but
it doesn't work:

```
(defn some-function2 [some-string]
(re-find #(str "(?i)" some-string) "some sentence"))
```

I'm surprised this doesn't work since LISP is supposed to "treat code like data".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421044/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-macro-to-create-a-regular-expression-from-a-string

Comment: The term "var" means something very specific in Clojure, and `some-string` isn't a var. It's just a function parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the function [re-pattern](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/re-pattern). #"" is just a reader macro (aka. syntactic sugar for creating regex)

#(str "(?i)" some-string) is reader macro to create an anonymous functions.

Comment: I agree, `re-pattern` is the easiest way to do this. It builds up a regex pattern from a string. To answer OP's question, you could do `(re-find (re-pattern (str "(?i)" some-string)) "some sentence")`.

Answer (score 7):

To create a pattern from a string value in Clojure you can use re-pattern:

```
(re-pattern (str "(?i)" some-string))
```

One thing you don't mention is whether `some-string` is expected to contain a valid regex or whether it's an arbitrary string value. If `some-string` is an arbitrary string value (that you want to match exactly) you should quote it before using it to build your regex:

```
(re-pattern (str "(?i)" (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote some-string)))
```